# Matrix scalar product

Tags: c++

I have a task to calculate a  scalar product

```
s=(B*(r+q+r), A*A*p)
```

As I understand, I need to calculate 2 vectors: first - B*(r+q+r), second - A*A*p, and then calculate a scalar product.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using matrix = vector<vector<double>>;

matrix add(matrix A, matrix B) {
    matrix C;
    C.resize(A.size());
    for (int i = 0; i< A.size(); i++) {
        C[i].resize(B.size());
        for (int j = 0; j < B.size(); j++) {
            C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
        }
    }
    return C;
}

matrix multiple(matrix A, matrix B)
{
    matrix C;
    C.reserve(100);
    C.resize(B.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        C[i].resize(B.size());
        for (int j = 0; j < B.size(); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < B.size(); k++)
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
        }
    }
    return C;
}

void main() {
    matrix A = { {1,2,3}, {1,2,1}, {3,2,0} };
    matrix B = { {4,1,2},{0,4,3},{1,1,1} };
    matrix r = { {-0.7f, 1.3, 0.2} };
    matrix q = { { -1.6f, 0.8, 1.1} };
    matrix p = { {0.1, 1.7, -1.5} };


    matrix r_q = add(r, q);

    for (int i = 0; i < r_q.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < r_q.size(); j++) {
            cout << r_q[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    matrix a_a = multiple(A, A);
    matrix a_a_p = multiple(a_a,p);

    getchar();
}
```

Problems:

1. add method work not correct, it put in result only one number - sum of the first items.
2. Multipling matrix with the same dimensions (A*A) work correct.  Multipling matrix with the different dimensions (a_a * p) - return error "vector subscript out of range".

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: In `add` try changing `C[i].resize(B.size());` to `C[i].resize(A[i].size());` and also add checks to make sure that A and B have the same dimensions.

Comment: In multiply matrix you need to check the dimensions 1st to make sure it is even possible to multiply the two matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The OP chose to implement *both* matrices *and* vectors using a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`.

This may not be a good design choice in general, but also in particular, to be consistent to the mathematical meaning of all the involved operations, all the vectors should be considered (and declared as well) as "column" matrices (or Nx1 matrices):

```
matrix r = { {-0.7}, {1.3}, {0.2} };
matrix q = { {-1.6}, {0.8}, {1.1} };
matrix p = { {0.1}, {1.7}, {-1.5} };
```

Then, in the functions that perform the calculations, special attention should be paid to the correct sizes of rows and columns to avoid out of bounds accesses.

```
matrix add(matrix const &A, matrix const &B)
{
    if (A.size() != B.size()  ||  A.size() == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("number of rows mismatch");

    size_t columns = A[0].size();
    matrix C(A.size(), std::vector<double>(columns, 0.0));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
        if ( A[i].size() != columns  ||  B[i].size() != columns )
            throw std::runtime_error("number of columns mismatch");
        for (size_t j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
        }
    }
    return C;
}

matrix multiple(matrix const &A, matrix const &B)
{
    if ( A.size() == 0  ||  B.size() == 0  ||  B[0].size() == 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("size mismatch");

    size_t columns = B[0].size();
    matrix C(A.size(), std::vector<double>(columns, 0.0));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
    {
        if ( A[i].size() != B.size()  ||  B[i].size() != columns )
            throw std::runtime_error("inner size mismatch");

        for (size_t j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < B.size(); k++)
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
        }
    }
    return C;
}
```

The compiler should have also warned the OP about the incorrect use of `void main` instead of `int main` and about the comparisons between signed and unsigned integer expressions (I used `size_t` instead of `int`).

From a mathematical point of view, it's worth noting that to solve OP problem, that is to calculate the scalar product *s* = (**B**(**r**+**q**+**r**), **AAp**), the operations really needed (to be implemented) are the sum of vectors, the product of a matrix by a vector (easier and more efficient then matrix multiplication) and the dot product of two vectors:

**t** = **r** + **q** + **r**

**b** = **Bt**

**u** = **Ap**

**a** = **Au**

*s* = (**b**, **a**)